# "menu > li:first-child" as variable for "getBoundingClientRect().left"

Tags: variables, css-selectors, getboundingclientrect

I have the follow hierarchy:

```
menu > li:first-child
menu > li:nth-child(2)
menu > li:nth-child(3)
menu > li:nth-child(4)
menu > li:nth-child(5)
menu > li:nth-child(6)
menu > li:nth-child(7)
menu > li:nth-child(8)
menu > li:nth-child(9)
```

I am trying to put each of these in to a variable in order to:

```
var fromleft = box.getBoundingClientRect().left;
var fromtop = box.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

It works right now with:

```
var box = document.getElementById('menu');
var fromleft = box.getBoundingClientRect().left;
var fromtop = box.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

but not with:

```
var box = document.getElementById('menu > li:first-child');
var fromleft = box.getBoundingClientRect().left;
var fromtop = box.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

What do I need to do in order to use first-child or nth-child in a variable?

Comment: I came across this and I think it is what I need, still testing however!


"var box = document.getElementById( 'sdt_menu' ).getElementsByTagName( 'li' )[2];"

Answer (score 0):

I came across this and I think it is what I needed!

```
var box = document.getElementById( 'sdt_menu' ).getElementsByTagName( 'li' )[0];"
```

And... 0 = first-child, 1 = nth-child(2), ect

Also... 'li' can be changed to 'div' and others.

(or so it seems!)